# Cast Error after change _id number in url path

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey I have one question how dispaly information when product is no found in database? Because now when I change _id number in url I get error `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5962088db4457a0aec3d9d4dh" at path "_id" for model "User"`

api.js

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
    var editUser = req.params.id;
    User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }, function(err, mainUser) {
        if(err) throw err
        if(!mainUser) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'User no found'});
        } else {
            if(mainUser.permission === 'admin' || mainUser.permission === 'moderator') {
                User.findOne({ _id: editUser }, function(err,user) {
                    if(err) throw err
                    if(!user) { 
                        res.json({ success: false, message: 'User no found' });
                    } else {
                        res.json({ success: true, user: user });
                    }
                })
            } else {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'You are not an admin' });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

routes.js

```
.when('/edit/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/management/edit.html',
    controller: 'editCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'edit',
    authenticated: 'true',
    permission: ['admin', 'moderator']
})
.otherwise({redirectTo : '/'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a validation check on id before query into database

```
var objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

    if(objectid.isValid(editUser)){
    //your all code here
    }
    else
    {
     res.json({ success: false, message: 'invalid id' });
    }
```

Comment: have you installed "mongodb" package?

Comment: could you look on my last question in this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802820/redirect-url-path-if-object-id-will-not-found-in-database